# Fulltext score taking a long time to calculate

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, innodb

I have a query that returns 5 records in 14.6ms. Just a basic query on an index:

```
SELECT
    eidr_id
    # match(search) against ('warncdfomMPMd4153463 105240E244CC76351C744DC9B9') x
FROM
    eidrdedupe_records
WHERE
    structural_type=1
    AND root_parent_eidr_id='10.5240/E244-CC76-351C-744D-C9B9-T'
    AND points_to_eidr_id=''
```

[image]

However, as soon as I uncomment the full-text score (needed for stuff I do down-stream), the query time takes 40x longer -- which I don't understand since it's only running the FTS on those five records.

[image]

Why is this occurring, and is there a way to improve this?

Comment: While calculating ranking, not only these 5 rows are taking into account. If one word is rare across all records it has higher ranking that not rare word.

Comment: @fifonik could you please elaborate?

Comment: It is described in [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html). Rank is per all items. So when you adding the 'match against' the query started to use full  text index and use it to calculate rank taking all indexed items into account.

Comment: What happens if you add the `match...` to the `WHERE` clause (in addition to putting it in the `SELECT` part?